# How do I run a .py module in Aptana?

Tags: eclipse, macos, ide, aptana, pydev

Every time I try to run a .py module it just opens in Firefox.

I'm running Aptana in OS X 10.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed and configured PyDev, it should work.

Make sure you use the correct "Run" command. Prefer "Run as Python module", avoid "Run on Server".

If that doesn't help, edit your question and give an exact example what you do (which menus/buttons you click, etc).

Comment: Under Run As it says (Non applicable)

Comment: I do not have the "Python Run" option for some reason :-(

Answer (score 0):

See: http://pydev.org/manual_101_run.html for details on running a Python module (make sure you read the whole getting started: http://pydev.org/manual_101_root.html which should help you in getting your environment setup and gives some tips to properly use PyDev).

Answer (score 0):

I used a same workspace for both python and java , and met the same problem.
If I change a new workspace, the Run As works. So i think there is something wrong with workspace settings.